# redux-observable unit test epci with dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, redux-observable

I have an epic with the following signature (note the dependency)

```
export const incrementalSearchEpic = (action$, store, { incrementalSearchService }) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
    return action$.ofType('SEARCH_STORES').mergeMap((action) =>
        incrementalSearchService.performIncrementalSearch(action)
    );
};
```

Now I need to unit test this and this is my unit testing code

```
beforeEach(() => {
    epicMiddleWare = createEpicMiddleware(incrementalSearchEpic,
        {
            dependencies: {
                incrementalSearchService: IncrementalSearchServiceMock
            }
        });
    const mockStore = configureMockStore([epicMiddleWare]);
    const getState = {}; // initial state of the store         
    store = mockStore(getState);
});

// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
it('calls the incrementalSearchService->performIncrementalSearch with the parameters when called', () => {
    //dispatch the incremental search action
    const searchStore = {
        type: 'SEARCH_STORES',
        SearchText: 'Aldi'
    };

    store.dispatch(searchStore);

    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([
        searchStore
    ]);
});
```

However when I run the code I get the following error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'performIncrementalSearch' of undefined

Seems like the dependency does not get passed in properly.

Comment: What version of redux-observable is installed?

Comment: redux-observable version: 0.14.1
Its working when I run the main app, its just on the unit test it fails.

Comment: Everything presented here looks fine, assuming it's identical to the code you're using. I don't think I'll be any help unfortunately. I would pause the debugger at the very beginning of the epic, before returning your stream, confirm dependencies is undefined, then walk the callstack back and see why--you should be able to see the cause this way.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized: if redux-observable wasn't injecting the provided dependencies object you'd actually get `Cannot read property 'incrementalSearchService' of undefined` not performIncrementalSearch because redux-observable does not inject an object by default--it's not erroring because it is indeed passing your object.

Instead, the likely problem is that your import or definition of `IncrementalSearchServiceMock` is actually `undefined`. Perhaps a wrong named import or similar.

If you can't immediately see why, pause your debugger at the beginning of beforeEach and confirm the value of `IncrementalSearchServiceMock` is not undefined.